# Parallax effect with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parallax

I'm trying to make a parallax effect in React and I have an error like that:

[image: Cannot set property 'backgroundPositionY' of undefined]

Here is my code in a JavaScript file for parallax:

```
  export const parallax = document.getElementsByClassName("parallax");

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    let offset = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log("offset", offset)
    parallax.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * 0.7 + "px";
  })
```

And in my JSX file, I'm importing this file like that:

```
import parallax from './parallax'
```

So when I log the offset I can see the different values but it doesn't work with `parallax.style.backgroundPositionY` and I don't understand why.
Your help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array of DOM elements, you could replace it with `document.getElementById` or iterate over the array elements.

Comment: You can use react-parallax for creation this effect, maybe it help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0yekozrw?from-embed=&file=/index.js:89-103

Comment: Ok thank you @CerebralFart but with `document.getElementById` I have an error like `cannot read property 'style' of null ` ...

Comment: Yes thank you @DenisStukalov I saw this library and I used it in another project but I wanted to create this effect myself for practice..

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here. If you use your current approach, `parallax` will be a nodelist and depending how many nodes are inside, you would have to filter it for the correct one. If there is only one, you would only have to change your code to

```
  export const [parallax, ...notNeeded] = document.getElementsByClassName("parallax");
```

This will assign the first element to the variable `parallax` and all remaining ones into `notNeeded`. But a better solution in this case would be to use `querySelector`. It will return the first node, which matches the condition:

```
const parallax = document.querySelector(".parallax");
```